# What is the standard way of working with active directory

Tags: active-directory, standards

I have a software that needs to work with active directory. It should work on different server machines for different companies. It should create new groups, roles.

Each server computer can have different `OU structure.`

Should I create my own `OU folder` for my groups? Is there any specific directory or place where I need to create my `application OU?` Maybe those companies should tell me how to manage their active directory? 
Basically, I am asking what is the proper way of working with active directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard answer to this question.  Each admin (company) can and will set things up differently.

Some will create hundreds of OU's, and have each application in it's own, while others may not create any, and leave everything in default containers.

Personally, I try not to over create OU's in AD, because it can make it hard to find things, but again, that is my personal style.  I've seen setups where just about every project got it's own OU's.